# How to delete the video file along with the selected adapter in a listview?

Tags: java, android, file, adapter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete entry and video file in a listview file browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003439/how-to-delete-entry-and-video-file-in-a-listview-file-browser)

Problem description: I wanted a "delete" function which is able to delete the adapter when it is clicked in a listview and at the same time it will delete the appropriate/residing video file in the Video_List directory? How should i do that in my current codes below?

I'm rather new in android/java can someone help me with it? Do scroll down to take a better look at my problem please, i really at a lost here..