# How to delete entry and video file in a listview file browser?

Tags: java, android, file, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Problem description: I wanted a "delete" function which could perform delete/remove of the selected entry in a listview and at the same time delete the residing video file string in the Video_List directory then it refresh the content of the listview?

I'm rather new in android/java can someone help me with it? Do scroll down to evaluate the problem i'm facing please!! Can someone tell me what is the specific code i should add into my current codes to perform the above mention function??

Comment: @dhaag23 i wanted to perform deleting of video files?? Do scroll down to the bottom of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have stored your selection into "item" object then in deleteFile() method you need to retreive the file path from that object, for that to work add the line:

> model.absolutePath =
> mfile.getAbsolutePath();

in getVideoFiles() method 'for' loop.

also before onCreate state:

> ListViewAdapter lv;

then in getVideoFiles at the end state:

```
  lv = new ListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row, videoItems);
  setListAdapter(lv);
```

finally in deleteFile() you need to state:

> File myFile = new File(item.absolutePath);
>
> lv.notifyDataSetChanged();

and that should work!

Comment: @Lumis that is the puzzling part i'm stuck with, i'm been stuck with this problem for days without any real progress to delete the selected file and entry in the listview!!! Can you me solve my problem please... I'm rather new in android/java...

Comment: @Lumis by the way do you know how to transfer/archive the entry and video file to another file directory listview activity?

Comment: @Lumis Do you know how to copy/transfer video files and listview entry to another listview activity?

Comment: You just need to find out how to copy the file into another folder and then apply the same code with different path: File filePath = new File("/sdcard/Video_List")

Comment: @Lumis i have a proble here can you take a look --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007705/how-to-copy-transfer-video-files-and-listview-entry-to-another-listview-activity

Comment: @Lumis i still don't quite get what you are suggesting to transfer the selected video file and entry listview to another directory?

Answer (score 0):

You defined an override onListItemClick but this code is never been called. You should also register the a listener to the view you're using. Check how android handle [user interface events.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html)

```
newListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Comment: I think you better understand the concept and read the link I gave you. That line of code should work if you properly understand it.

Comment: what does that line has to do with deleting entries and video files in my ow context?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to delete the adapter or do you want to delete a row/entry in the list? If latter, then update videoItems and call notifyDataSetChanged on your adapter. If you really want to delete the adapter, then just set it to NULL or have it refer to some other ListAdapter instance and the GC will take care of the rest.

Comment: @user693959 i want to delete the video file and at the same time remove the adapter item that is being click or else the apter will still persist in the listview isn't it? Can you help i really have no idea how to do the above function?

Comment: replace: deleteFile(); with deleteFile(v, position); Use the view passed in to get the name of the file to be deleted: (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext).getText().toString(). When the user confirms the delete, then perform file operation to delete the file and then delete the entry in your data list videoItems.remove(position). Finally, update the listView by getListAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged() to refresh your listview. HTTH.

Comment: @user693959 still very blur with your explanation?? With error such as  deleteFile(v, position); getListAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged().. Sorry i'm rather very bad in programming, not knowing where i should really put the appropriated code you are mentioning above?? Haiz...

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override // create contextuel menu 
            public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
                menu.setHeaderTitle("Action");

                menu.add(0,100,1,"delete");

            }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    @Override // Select an item 
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            final AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            switch(item.getItemId()){
            case 100:
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    db.delete_item(info.id);

                    //here update list view
    }
    });

    ////////////

    public boolean delete_item(long id){ 

    return db.delete("name_table", "_id="+id, null)>0;}
    ////////////////
```